# html element inside ng-if appear when the page is loading

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

On my page I have a div inside ng-if  when there is a number of scripts to load ,i.e when the page is not fully loaded.The div is visible. How do I hide it unless page/angular is fully loaded.

```
<div  id = "menu"  ng-if="someCondition" >
    <ul class="user-menu">
        <li>
            menu item 1 
        </li>
        <li>
            menu item 2 
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation for [ng-cloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak).

From the documentation:

> The ngCloak directive is used to prevent the Angular html template
>   from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled)
>   form while your application is loading. Use this directive to avoid
>   the undesirable flicker effect caused by the html template display.

Also:

> The directive can be applied to the  element, but the preferred
>   usage is to apply multiple ngCloak directives to small portions of the
>   page to permit progressive rendering of the browser view.

```
<div  id = "menu"  ng-if="someCondition" ng-cloak>
    <ul class="user-menu">
        <li>
            menu item 1 
        </li>
        <li>
            menu item 2 
        </li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

How it works:

The following styles are applied to the document (the angular.js file is essentially acting as a .css file) when angular.js is loaded (which is recommended to be in the head of your page).  When angular actually runs on DOM load, it removes the ng-cloak attribute, uncloaking the elements.

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}
```

If you don't load angular in the head of your document, then you can add the styles manually to the head and everything will still work.  Just add

```
<style type="text/css">
    [ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
        display: none !important;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a guess due to the fact that you only provided a small code snippet but my guess is that the controller is not initialized yet ( under the hood angular will parse through your HTML DOM and act accordingly when it is called. )

If you use a simple route this would prevent this completely.

Alternatively you could place all of your ng-if conditions with a css display:none; and then iterate through all of them once the app has completed loading

Comment: ng-cloak applied to the body element does your alternative automatically.

Comment: assuming that angular has actually loaded the question stated page/angular, so in the event that angular is still downloading (slow internet connection, uncompressed angular, lots of other scripts from the same CDN, etc. and the test server on local network)  then ng-cloak would not be able to run until after the angular bootstrap has downloaded and been parsed. Using a simple route would be (imho) the cleanest way because this way the template cannot get loaded unless everything has been initialized, otherwise a hand-rolled method could still work.

Comment: If you include angular.js in the head of the document (recommended) it will do it automatically (before angular "runs", which happens after the DOM has loaded.  It does this by doing exactly what you suggest (adding display:none style that affects any element with an ng-cloak attribute, and then removing the style after the DOM has been parsed by angular.

Comment: what my point is that the dom can still be loading and the angular.js script can take quite a while to actually get downloaded (even if its in the head tag) ) I just opened the source to the uncompressed angular.js that I have here on my machine, no init is performed until line 22024 of the file ( which is after approximately 764kb into the file. ) There is no way for ng-cloak to do anything until the angular library has loaded fully (im not talking about app.init, im talking about the libraries bootstrap) Throw in a few poor choices and I can see this being a serious issue.

Comment: Browsers will not display anything until after scripts (and any other elements) in the head section are downloaded and executed.  So if angular.js is in the head of the page, ng-cloak will always work as expected, just like a style sheet or style element in the head section will always work.   If this were not the case, even your solution wouldn't work, because there is a chance the stylesheet with your display:none wouldn't have downloaded by the time the DOM started to get rendered.

Comment: I've updated my answer for the cases where angular.js is included somewhere other than the head of the document.  It's as simple as adding the same css that angular.js adds.  There is no need to iterate over the nodes of your document (as you suggest), because angular does that for you.

Comment: I have slapped together an example of Angular being loaded with a mocked up dependancy manager, it should work in an almost identical manner to jquery include, browserify, bower, etc. ) angular is being served up by a php script that rate limits the download to 100kbps, the html page contains 3 lines (one of which is hidden away inside ng-cloak. Take a look: http://boot.p0ssess3d.net/slowAngular/example1.php

Comment: Good example, although technically you still aren't including angular in the <head> element.  Script that are dynamically created and added to a document are async by default.  Heres a modified [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/3UIEM24KiNuvuUjwdc95?p=preview) that uses your example with my solution.

Comment: I really like your css to perform the cleanup (it is much cleaner than my solution of cleanup via hand-rolled JS. ) While I am not "technically" loading it in the head element (it is being done so indirectly.). it appears that package and dependency managers are becoming more and more common.

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional operator.

```
<div id="menu" ng-if="someCondition.length > 0 ? true : false">
    <ul class="user-menu">
        <li>
            menu item 1 
        </li>
        <li>
            menu item 2 
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```